# Record insert fails using Entity Framework Core in Azure Function(works in development environment)

Tags: azure-functions, entity-framework-6

I have a Azure function v4 app that reads a csv file and populates few tables in Azure SQL database using Entity Framework Core 6. In local everything works as expected, the problem starts when deployed to Azure

Startup.cs -> Inject database and service to function app

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => 
  options.UseSqlServer(DatabaseConnectionString, sqloptions => sqloptions.CommandTimeout(1000)) ); 

builder.Services.AddTransient<IClientService, ClientService>();
```

ClientService.cs

```cs
public class ClientService()
{
    ...
    public ClientService(DBContext dbContext)
    {
      _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    ..
    
    public void Process()
    {
      var fileRecords = //gets file records
      ...
      
      // Insert to table 1
      foreach(var item in fileRecords)
      {
        _dbContext.table1.add(item);
      }
      
      _dbContext.SaveChanges(); // Inserts 70 records
      
      ...
      
      // Insert to table 2
      foreach(var item in fileRecords)
      {
        _dbContext.table2.add(item);
        
        // Save changes inside for each
        // inserts 100 records
        //_dbContext.SaveChanges();  
      }
      
      // Save changes outside for each
      // inserts 0 records
      _dbContext.SaveChanges(); 
    }
}
```

Function.cs

```cs
[FunctionName("ImportCsVToAzureSqlDB")]
public async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 0 1 * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
{
  _clientService.Process();
}
```

I have been using AppInsights as logger, the logger stops in between logging messages from EFCore. What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Below are the config file contents

host.json

```js
{
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "2.0"
}
```

local.settings.json

```js
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureSqlDB": "<Connection string>",
  },
}
```

Comment: could you please provide the `host.json` and `local.setting.json` file code here!

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT updated host.json and local.settings.json. I deployed to Azure Function Consumption Premium plan and also with AppService plan both behave same.

Comment: make sure your connection string is set. got to your function in the portal, check configuration

Comment: @RomanSvitukha the connection string all looks good. The function app does insert for the first foreach. It's the next of foreach when the behaviour is weird. FYI the program also has another dbcontext for a different Azure SQL Server database to which select query calls are made and there's no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, actually the issue was a simple FK violation on some records. The problem was Entity Framework did not throw error and the run just stops abruptly. Here is how i got the exception, incase anyone else faces same problem. You need to create seperate context for each table insert, once i did this the error started to show up. I'm not sure on why EF Core behaves this way. After i fixed the FK issue i'm able to run with the regular code.

```html
    using (var context = new DbContext()) 
    { 
        foreach(..)
        {
          // insert table 1
        }

        context.SaveChanges(); 
    }
    
    using (var context = new DbContext()) 
    { 
        foreach(..)
        {
          // insert table 2
        }

        context.SaveChanges(); 
    }
```